# CSS: Size of buttons in Chrome is different than Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have the following HTML code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.submitbutton{margin-left:-2px;padding:1px}
</style>
...
<form> 
... 
<input class=submitbutton type=submit value="Create Listings" /> 
</form>
```

In Firefox, the input button has more padding than in Chrome.

Any ideas why?

UPDATE: If you're wondering why I have the negative margin - it's because between the input field and the input button - there is too much space.

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting the width through style?

Answer (score 67):

```
/* Remove button padding in FF */
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

You'll get the same button appearance in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: I found I had to also give a negative margin to get Firefox buttons to match Chromium ones.

Comment: I had to give you a +1 for this, immensely helpful!  Why can't you see the Mozilla proprietary pseudo classes in Firebug???  Chrome has them.

Comment: +1 as it seems to remove some random horizontal "padding" on the button text, but I still get 1px above and below the text that shouldn't be there.

Comment: { "Why can't you see the Mozilla proprietary pseudo classes in Firebug??? Chrome has them" } DOM Inspector addon can

Comment: You can't see that stuff in the built in developer tools in firefox either.

Answer (score 11):

Even though you as a developer test in different browsers and see the difference in buttons, the user will not. It's too easy to get focused on things that users won't notice:  the user likely has either Firefox or else IE or else Chrome, but not all of them. Rarely do users ever switch browsers over time let alone switch between them and complain about a few pixels diff.

So if you consider the buttons and the experience in just one browser at a time, and if it works well in that experience/browser, then don't bother spending more time. Instead move onto  next steps.

This doesn't answer 'why' but somebody else explained that one.

Comment: While that's true and I agree with it (I use that premise every day), button size affects both the usability and accessibility of a page.  With those in mind, a larger button target can be quite valuable.

Comment: That might be a good solution if your button is stand alone. But as soon it's right next to other elements that should have the same hight and are aligned on the bottom your layout will just break.

Answer (score 4):

form elements render differently(as defaults) depending on the OS and/or browser. if you want your form elements(input fields, submit buttons, etc.) to look  the same in all instances, you have to explicitly style them using borders, paddings and margins.

Comment: So I just added padding and it still doesn't help

Comment: like i said you still have to set the borders etc. if you want a button that looks like the "add comment" button here in SO, it has border: 1px solid #000, side padding of about 5px, background color of #ccc. (all approximations just on top of my head sorry :P)

Comment: You mean the "Post Your Answer" button?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
/* Browser Firefox to match the Chrome */
#buttonid::-moz-focus-inner, .buttonclass::-moz-focus-inner, button::-moz-focus-inner {
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing that no one is mentioning here is that Chrome resets the CSS for these elements:

```
input[type="button"],
input[type="submit"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="file"]::-webkit-file-upload-button,
button
```

So no matter what you set the padding to, as far as I can tell, it will be overridden by Chrome. I have tried using `!important` as well as other techniques and still no luck. If anyone has any insight into this I would love to know.

Comment: Here in SO the appearance of the 'Post Your Answer' button *is* overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `-webkit-box-sizing:content-box`, then read about box-models.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried now to modify height and padding in the same time.

The result it's quite good. Seems to be correct for both browsers (FF and Chrome in Linux)... for example i've put:

```
.classname {
height:20px;
    padding:4px;
}
```

Maybe it's just my lucky day... however you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same size on both browser you have to set the same initial values to all the CSS elements, like a reset.

This is how I fixed the problem:
put this at the beginning of your css file

```
body, div, dl, dt, dd, ul, ol, li, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, pre, code, form, fieldset, legend, input, button, textarea, p, blockquote, th, td, a
    {
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      margin-left: 0px;
      padding-top: 0px;
      padding-right: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-left: 0px;
      border-top-width: 0px;
      border-right-width-value: 0px;
      border-bottom-width: 0px;
      border-left-width-value: 0px;
    }
```

Now you have to fix some aspect changes on your page but it will look almost the same on all the browsers.