# Why is Firefox button larger?

Tags: html, css

```
.ui_btn , .sub_txt {
margin: 2px 0px 2px 3px;
background:#181c18;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform:lowercase;
}

.ui_btn input, .sub_txt input , .disabled input{
border-spacing: 0px; 
background: none;
color: #fff;
outline:0!important;
margin:0!important;
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
border: 1px solid #181c18;
font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
padding: 7px 6px!important;
white-space: nowrap;
text-transform:lowercase;
line-height: 12px!important;
}
```

And this is my button:

```
<label id="SD_mrs_t" class="ui_btn" for="SD_mrs">
<input id="SD_mrs" value="More Specific" type="button"/>
</label>
```

As a result button in Firefox has something like:

```
padding: 9px 8px!important;
```

Is there any solution without definition of special parameters for Mozilla browser?

Answer (score 23):

Firefox applies a [special padding to buttons](http://ov-ms.com/2010/06/fix-firefox-button-padding/), which you can address like this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner {
     padding: 0 !important;
     border: 0 none !important;
 }
```

Comment: You're welcome. You should upvote and accept the answer (the "up" arrow and the hook below the "0"), that worked for you. I suggest kasimir's, because he was first.

Comment: Thanks, well if @fug3lla won't accept mine, I could upvote yours to make sure the correct answer will stay on top... ;-)

Answer (score 9):

In Firefox, the input button has more padding, this might help to resolve it:

```
/* Remove button padding in FF */
button::-moz-focus-inner {
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Also, this question seems more or less the same (above code is suggested there): [CSS: Size of buttons in Chrome is different than Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954659/css-size-of-buttons-in-chrome-is-different-than-firefox)

Answer (score -1):

If you use a reset.css in your stylesheet, it can set the default values for all browsers on load, then the firefox button wouldn't be bigger. I use this one:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: That's what I would do, the best way may be to define the parameters for firefox directly then, but i'd wait for a minute first seeing as someone here is bound to have an answer.