# Uploading image file using php

Tags: php

I am using this to upload file in php

```
 Image <input type="file" name="file" />
```

It's working.but the background is white so it's  not visible well, means it's not working as given in this [link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/051e29/image-uploading-in-php/).I can't modify my background, it should be white.Also by default, the text is "no file selected", can i modify it ? please help

Comment: Can't believe an article written in 2012 still uses `bgcolor`

Comment: @AyeshK ok fine.Can you solve problem ? or can you give some idea ?

Comment: @David no it doesn't.

Comment: It seems like that article is basic PHP tips for C# Guys!

Comment: @JensonMJohn anything u can give about pure php for uploading image?

Comment: @AndroidKiller Hey that code works fine. That's the very basic example. If you want to change bgcolor, Change pink to white. <body bgcolor="pink"> & "no file chosen" is the default message I could see from Chrome 26.

Comment: @JensonMJohn read my answer again.i can't change my back ground color. i need it white.

Comment: Did you change bgcolor from pink to white in body?

Comment: @JensonMJohn man.. by default it is white....and i need that one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28824/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-android-killer)

Answer (score 0):

The style of an file input is regulated by the browser you're using (propably chrome in your case i think). But there are opportunities to style them with Javascript or CSS, look [here](https://www.google.ch/search?q=css%20input%20type%20submit%20not%20working%20ie&aq=f&oq=css%20input%20type%20submit%20not%20working%20ie&aqs=chrome.0.64j0.5217j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=de&sclient=psy-ab&q=javascript%7Cjquery%7Ccss3%20style%20file%20input&oq=javascript%7Cjquery%7Ccss3%20style%20file%20input&gs_l=serp.3...4606.6605.2.6682.12.12.0.0.0.4.192.1343.6j5.11.0...0.0...1c.1.11.psy-ab.bfpqZWSEtq4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45580626,d.bGE&fp=70393516d72f0caf&biw=1476&bih=878) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226167/how-to-style-input-file-with-css3-javascript).

Comment: yes i know, because there are lots of solutions :) one of them i like to use is [javanto's jQuery Fileinput Plugin](https://github.com/javanto/jquery-fileinput)

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers have different approach in displaying HTML elements. 
For eg. 
[CSS: Size of buttons in Chrome is different than Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954659/css-size-of-buttons-in-chrome-is-different-than-firefox)